# Procedure calling another procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE numeros (entra1 NUMBER, entra2 NUMBER)
IS
v_num1 NUMBER;
v_num2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
v_num1:=entra1;
v_num2:=entra2;
END;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE somando
IS
v_soma NUMBER;
v_num1 NUMBER;
v_num2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
numeros(40,60);
v_soma:=(v_num1+v_num2);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('O valor da soma de ' ||v_num1||' e '||v_num2||' é:'||v_soma);
END somando;
```

Why I can't catch the values from the first procedure "numeros", when I execute the procedure "somando" the result is empty " ".

Comment: `numeros` has no form of output, so you can put numbers in but nothing will come out...

Comment: How I make it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is PL/SQL, I believe there are a few possible workarounds for this. The easiest being to make output parameter variables in the procedure to get the numbers like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE numeros(
    entra1 IN NUMBER,
    entra2 IN NUMBER,
    out_entra1 OUT NUMBER,
    out_entra2 OUT NUMBER)
IS
    v_num1 NUMBER;
    v_num2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_num1 := entra1;
    v_num2 := entra2;
    out_entra1 := v_num1;
    out_entra2 := v_num2;
END numeros;

    ----------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE somando IS
    v_soma NUMBER;
    v_num1 NUMBER;
    v_num2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.enable();
    numeros(40,60,v_num1,v_num2);
    v_soma := (v_num1+v_num2);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('O valor da soma de ' ||v_num1||' e '||v_num2||' é:'||v_soma);

END somando;
```

I believe a more recommended method would be to place these two procedures in a package and declare global variables in the header, but I'm not sure what your set up is like.

Answer (score -1):

You can either change the procedure to a function that returns the value, or specify one of the arguments to the procedure to be IN OUT

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! :)

Comment: This should be under comment, It cannot be treated as a valid answer. You need to give relevant examples and explaination to support your answer.